# a code piece from MLIR that make me confused

Tags: c++, llvm

There is a code piece from the llvm-project/mlir/lib/IR/Dialect.cpp

```
void DialectRegistry::insert(TypeID typeID, StringRef name,
                             const DialectAllocatorFunction &ctor) {
  auto inserted = registry.insert(
      std::make_pair(std::string(name), std::make_pair(typeID, ctor)));
  if (!inserted.second && inserted.first->second.first != typeID) {
    llvm::report_fatal_error(
        "Trying to register different dialects for the same namespace: " +
        name);
  }
}
```

The type of `registry` is `std::map<std::string, std::pair<TypeID, DialectAllocatorFunction>>`, which can be find in llvm-project/mlir/lib/IR/DialectRegistry.h. Thus the type of `inserted` should be something like `pair<map<std::string(name), std::make_pair(typeID, ctor)>::iterator, bool>`, then `inserted.first` should be of `map<std::string(name), std::make_pair(typeID, ctor)>` type, and then `inserted.first->second` should be of `std::make_pair(typeID, ctor)` type, and finally `inserted.first->second.first` should have the same type of `typeID`, thus `inserted.first->second.first` can be compared with `typeID` in the `if` clause.

My question is that, isn't the `typeID` in the `std::make_pair(typeID, ctor)` expression assigned by the function parameter `TypeID typeID`? If it is, and the `typeID` in the `if` clause should also be assigned by the function parameter `TypeID typeID`, then in what condition can the two `typeID`s be different? Actually I do encounter with the fatal error cause by the two `typeID`s do not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a closer look at what the first entry of the [return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert#Return_value) of `std::map::insert` is:

> 1-3) Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element **(or to the element that prevented the insertion)** and a `bool` denoting whether the insertion took place.

(Emphasis added.)

If the insertion fails because an element was already present, `inserted.first` will be an iterator pointing to the value that prevented insertion. That is, if `registry` already has an entry for `name`, `inserted.first` will be an iterator pointing to a pair with the same name, but a possibly different `pair<TypeId, DialectAllocatorFunction>` than the arguments passed to `DialectRegistry::insert`